# Tomcat in Eclipse. Can not find

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I have downloaded the tomcat tar file from the official source and then I put it in /usr/share/tomcat7 directory and added the PATH variables as were suggested on the web.

Now I can run it via the command /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/startup.sh and it works fine.

I want to integrate this with eclipse. But when I do add new server, it just shows Basic. there is no apache directory. What should I do

thanks.

Here;s the screenshot[image: of server page. No Apache]

Comment: You mean to say you in your eclipse you are able to see apache tomcat option.??

Comment: @prashantthakre no, check screenshot.

Comment: First of all installing the tomcat in your drive and tomcat server adopter having no relationship.In your eclipse you don't have tomcat plugin/adopter hence you are not able to see it.May i know which version of eclipse you are using.You can configure your local apache tomcat once you are having same version of tomcat plugin/adopter in your eclipse.

Comment: @prashantthakre Eclipse 3.8

Comment: Are you able to create "web dynamic project" in your eclipse ??If not means something is wrong in your eclipse.You have go for higher version.

Comment: Yeah, I can create web dynamic project.

Comment: I am using 3.8. Isnt that good enough?

Comment: Now right click and select option run as ->run on server and check what options are coming

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59058/discussion-between-prashant-thakre-and-kraken).

Comment: Please check my answer given below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on "Download additional server adotpers" and choose apache option and download install the correct version of "Apache tomcat adopter".

You can see your posted screen where "Download additional server adotpers" link is there.

Comment: where do I get Download additional server adopters?

Comment: Yeah. But in the list, I do not see tomcat anywhere.

Comment: You have posted screen in that screen you can see there is blue color link  for "Download additional server adopters" just click on that link and proceed further

Answer (score 0):

If there is only Basic server option at there you have wrong eclipse version.

I have Eclipse Kepler. You can use Eclipse Juno or Luna.

[This link is usefull for you.](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/)